# global sections of the hyperplane line bundle on projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective subvariety in the complex projective space $\mathbf{P}^n$. Let $\mathcal{O}(1)$ be the hyperplane line bundle on $\mathbf{P}^n$. Then for $k \ge 1$,  the restriction $H^0(\mathbf{P}^n, \mathcal{O}(k))$ (the space of global sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbf{P}^n$) to $X$ is a subspace of $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(k)|_X)$ (the space of global sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)|_X$ on $X$). My question is:  are they equal for $k$ big enough (maybe in some situations)? or is there some standard information relating these two spaces?

As far as I can see, by using some standard exact sequences, one can prove that these two spaces are the same if $X$ is a smooth hypersurface and $k$ big enough.

Comment: Yes, for large $k$ they are equal. Serre vanishing.

Comment: I don't understand. The first space is not a subspace of the second in general. Consider eg ${\bf P}^1$ and $X$ a point. I think that what wnx means is that the natural map from the first to the second is surjective for large $k$.